# Is there any possible way to move character from one column to another?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, move

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

These are my available libraries. I want to move character from one column to another column of string. I can use scanf to detect which character I want to move and where I want to move the character. Let´s say I have

```
 char col[][]
```

That have 2 columns and 2 rows with random characters that looks like this

| a | | .. |

| b | | .. |

And I want to move character "a" to the second column so I have

| .. | | .. |

| b |  | a |

Columns and rows can be randomly big

What I need is to make

```
void move_characters(const int rows, const int columns, char col[rows][columns], int x, int y)
{

}
```

Note : All I need is to move characters, I already have constucted array with characters in it. I don´t need to move a specific character. I need to move character from the top of that column. Thanks.

| .. | is empty position   == ' '

int x = number of column/row, from which I want to move character

int y = number of column/row, to which I want to move character

Characters moves to the bottom of the column or if there already is a character it moves on top of that character.

Comment: Hm. Delete from one position and add to the other?

Comment: The requirements are not really well explained. What does "move" mean exactly? What value goes into the original location? You have shown `..` but what does that mean exactly? What does `x` and `y` represent? etc.

Comment: `col[1][1] = col[0][0];` ?

Comment: You need 2 parameters for the row and column where it's coming from, and 2 parameters for the row and column where it's moving to.

Comment: There is no such thing in memory as "empty". In your project what does an "empty" value look like. Also, each entry requires 2 indices to describe where they are. How does a single `x` value tell us which character to move?

Comment: @kaylum I don´t need to move a specific character.  X stands for number of array, from which I want to move character. So it moves character from the top of that column.

Comment: "Number of array" doesn't make sense. There is only one (2D) array. You need to talk about rows and columns to be clear. And then from "top of column" to where? Is it always to row 1, column Y? a 2D array requires 2 indices for each element. So your description is still not well defined. Perhaps give some example values of X and Y and then describe what the exact before and after is supposed to be.

Comment: does it always move to the bottom of the destination column? Does it "stack" on values previously moved like Connect-4? If not, you need to specify a destination row also, as already mentioned.

Comment: @yano Yes it moves to the end or bottom of the destination column

Comment: Ok, so it seems `x` specifies *both* the row and the column. Wish you said that from the beginning to save everyone alot of time. So it seems you just want `col[y][y] = col[x][x]; col[x][x] = ' ';` Yes? No?

Comment: So `col[rows-1][y] = col[0][x];`

Comment: sorry for mistakes. I m pretty new to the whole programming and stackoverflow. Thank you all for your patience

Comment: oh so from your latest edit the characters _are_ supposed to stack. Ok, think I more or less understand the objective now... what have you tried? What part are you stuck on? Supplying an empty function stub and asking SO to complete your code isn't how this works. You need to show what you've tried and explain how it's not working as you expect.

Comment: and you don't need anything from `curses.h`, or `time.h`, unless there's more to this assignment than you've described here. `stdbool.h` and `stdlib.h` are maybes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that x was the source and y was the destination right?
The thing is that you need two values for each, one for rows and one for columns
then you can do something like this:

```
col[y1][y2]=col[x1][x2]; //Duplicates value from source to destination
```

Not sure what you mean by empty, there are two empties that come to my mind:

```
col[x1][x2] = "";  // "Empties" source
```

or

```
col[x1][x2] = NULL; // "Empties" source
```

Comment: One cannot assign `""` to `char`